# Union in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, union

I am working on a task in pyspark. The code runs fine until where I union four tables in the following way.

```
mainDF = typeAFrame.union(typeCFrame).union(typeDFrame).union(TypeCRedFrame).union(TypeANewFrame).distinct()
```

This keeps throwing an error  `"An error was encountered: Invalid status code '400' from http://10.15.104.153:8998/sessions/34/statements/1 with error payload: "requirement failed: Session isn't active."`

Then , I tried to perform each union one by one until I reach the main df and used the distinct function at the end in a separate line.

```
mainDF = typeAFrame.union(typeCFrame)

mainDF = mainDF.union(typeDFrame)
mainDF = mainDF.union(TypeCRedFrame)
mainDF = mainDF.union(TypeANewFrame)

mainDF = mainDF.distinct()
```

which is still not working. Keep getting the same error.

Can you suggest me a way to deal with this issue, please?

thanks from now for your time and help

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: can you perform a .count() operation on all the dfs separately and see if anyone of them is not working?

Comment: Presumably , you can get some idea from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275693/timeout-error-error-with-400-statuscode-requirement-failed-session-isnt-act
Additionally, you might wanna check driver and executor memory and if there is any overhead per se!!