# Getting error : Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am getting error while running pyspark in Jupyter Notebook using python 3.7 using this below code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark as ps

conf = ps.SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("sparK-mer")
conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","3600s")
sc = SparkContext('local') 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover, Word2Vec
```

I am reading the csv file based on the following code:

```
datanew = sqlContext.read.format("csv") \
   .options(header='true', inferschema='true') \
   .load("C://Users//mypath//data.csv")

parts = datanew.rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
datapysp = parts.map(lambda p: Row(uiid=p[0],title=(p[3].strip()),text=(p[4].strip())))
schemaString = "uiid title text"
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for  field_name in schemaString.split()]
schema = StructType(fields)
sqlContext.createDataFrame(datapysp, schema).show()
```

This is the error message, and I am receiving and there are columns mentioned UIID, Title and text.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o74.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:164)
```

I went through the answers provided here: 
[Pyspark socket timeout exception after application running for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417441/pyspark-socket-timeout-exception-after-application-running-for-a-while). I tried changing the code to this as per the answers provided.

```
import pyspark as ps

conf = ps.SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("sparK-mer")
conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","3600s")
sc = ps.SparkContext('local[4]', '', conf=conf)
```

I get the error saying Java gateway process exited before sending its port number while running this part sc = ps.SparkContext('local[4]', '', conf=conf).

Also tried like this, but still the same error which I received regarding Accept timed out.

```
 parts = datanew.rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    datapysp = parts.map(lambda p: Row(uiid=p[0],title=(p[3].strip()),text=(p[4].strip())))
    schemaString = "uiid title text"
    fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for  field_name in schemaString.split()]
    schema = StructType(fields)
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(datapysp, 
    schema).show().config("sqlContext.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10000s") 
    --added this but still the error is not being resolved.
```

I would appreciate if any one could help me with this. I am using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: can post some links that might help you. is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10s Interval between each executor's heartbeats to the driver. Heartbeats let the driver know that the executor is still alive and update it with metrics for in-progress tasks.

Looking at that, I belive you have a problem in the  `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` part of your code. I would suggest you increase the `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval`.

Comment: Thanks @Xilpex, I increased it to 36000s and it still the same. 
conf = ps.SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("sparK-mer")
newconf=conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","36000s")
sc = SparkContext('local',newconf) but it is still the same error

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your spark version with this snippet code:

```
print( "spark version=" ,SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate().version)
```

and pyspark version with pip command line:

```
pip show pyspark
```

If the version of pyspark is greater then your spark version,
Then you can use older version of pyspark by using this snippet:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("pyspark==[older_version]")
```

Or install new version of spark in your system