# PySpark error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting error "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out" while running pyspark using python 3.9.6 and spark 3.3.1.

Source code:

```
import json

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


with open('config.json') as cfg:
    json_data = json.load(cfg)
    dataset_path = json_data['Dataset']

# Init spark
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('A').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

# Load Dataset
df = spark.read.options(delimiter=';', inferSchema=True, header=True).csv(dataset_path);
df.show(5)

# Dataset preprocessing
# Converts integer to double and converts 'quality' column to categorical

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def condition(r):
    if r == 0:
        label = "bad"
    else:
        label = "good"
    return label


df = df.withColumn("NO2", df["NO2"].cast('double'))
df = df.withColumn("O3", df["O3"].cast('double'))
df = df.withColumn("PM10", df["PM10"].cast('double'))
df = df.withColumn("PM25", df["PM25"].cast('double'))

df = df.withColumn('quality', condition('quality'))

df.show(5)
```

It happens when I try to apply the condition function for dataframe.

The full stack trace:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)
    ... 24 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3084)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:327)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)
    ... 24 more
```

I have tried to google it but [the only appropriate question I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369591/getting-error-caused-by-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-accept-timed-out) is without answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to import "findspark"

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```